# AbstractMethodError when creating JdkHttpServer for JAX-RS

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, httpserver

I'm trying to create a Java server for a REST API and following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698899/jersey-and-jax-rs-ri2-missing-httpserverfactory) I used jersey's JdkHttpServer. I imported the necessary jars (from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server/2.30)), but when I start the server the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpHandlerContainerProvider.createContainer(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:58)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(JdkHttpServerFactory.java:78)
at PokerJAXRS.main(PokerJAXRS.java:16)
```

My code is the following:

```java
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import java.net.URI;

public class PokerJAXRS {

    private static String baseUri = "http://localhost:9998/";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URI bUri = URI.create(baseUri);

        HttpServer server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(bUri, new ResourceConfig(PokerResource.class));

        System.out.println("Server running");
        System.out.println("Visit: http://localhost:9998/");
        System.out.println("Hit return to stop...");
        System.in.read();
        server.stop(0);
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }
}
```

And in `PokerResource` I've got all the paths for the API. Am I missing some import or do I have to define anything else?

**EDIT:** These are all the jar libs I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Are you actually using Maven? If so, can you show your pom.xml. If not, can you show all the jars you have included.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha no, I'm not using Maven (I know it would be better but I wanted to try and do it without it, sorry), I'll update the question right now with the jar libs I'm using!

Comment: You have a bunch of different versions of Jersey. You should never mix versions. It will lead to errors like this. Download the RI Bundle [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey/download.html). The download links are bad, you need to use https instead of http. You can download either the latest 2.30 or the pre-major-change 2.25.1 bundle. Add all the jars. Remove all that you currently have. Make sure you get the same version of `jersey-container-jdk-http`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first recommendation, for anyone working with Java, is to consider a dependency management approach. As I'm more used to maven, I'll share here what worked for me as part of a Maven pom.xml file, but you can always address it as it suits better to you:

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.33</jersey.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

As you can notice, it's basically about not mixing different jersey versions. Finally, it's a good practice to control versions by using a property whenever it fits.